# Best practices for testable Spring controller url building

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, url

**Problem:**

I am adding tests and refactoring existing Spring @RestControllers.

The urls used to be hard coded in the Rest annotations.

```
@GetMapping("/api/v1/{taxonomy}/animals")
public List<String> getAnimals() {
  ...
}
```

**Naming scheme:**

I started moving them into constants. So the tests will be easier maintainable and not break on trivial url changes.

I came up with my own naming scheme for the url constants. (see the code at the end of the question for my complete scheme)

```java
public static final String SERVICE_URL = "/api/v1/{taxonomy}/animals";

public static final String PATH_VAR_ANIMAL = "animal";
```

Are there any best practices for this? I was unable to find somethings and all the examples I found use hard coded strings.

**Url construction:**

Also a co-worker pointed out that string concatenation for url construction is risky. e.g. somebody could forget a '/' at the start of one url part.

```
@PostMapping(URL_PART_ANIMAL + URL_PART_FUR)
```

Is there a preferred way to build this kind of urls as they are not complete but only the end of an actual url?

**Complete example:**

```
package com.huelfe.animal.api.v1.rest;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(AnimalController.SERVICE_URL)

public class AnimalController {

  public static final String SERVICE_URL = "/api/v1/{taxonomy}/animals";

  public static final String PATH_VAR_ANIMAL = "animal";
  public static final String URL_PART_ANIMAL = "/{" + PATH_VAR_ANIMAL + "}";

  public static final String URL_PART_RELATIVE = "/relative";
  public static final String URL_PART_RENAME = "/rename";
  public static final String URL_PART_FUR = "/fur";

  public static final String PARAM_NAME = "name";
  public static final String PARAM_FUR = "fur";


  @GetMapping
  public List<String> getAnimals() {
    ...
  }

  @GetMapping(value = URL_PART_RELATIVE)
  public Map<String, Collection<String>> getAnimalsRelatives() {
    ...
  }

  @PostMapping
  public Result doAdd(@RequestParam(value = PARAM_NAME) @NotBlank String newAnimal) {
    ...
  }

  @DeleteMapping(value = URL_PART_ANIMAL)
  public Result doRemove(@PathVariable(PATH_VAR_ANIMAL) String animal) {
    ...
  }

  @PutMapping(URL_PART_ANIMAL + URL_PART_RENAME)
  public Result doRename(
      @PathVariable(PATH_VAR_ANIMAL) String animal,
      @RequestParam(value = PARAM_NAME) @NotBlank String newName) {
    ...
  }

  @PostMapping(URL_PART_ANIMAL + URL_PART_FUR)
  public Result addFurs(
      @PathVariable(PATH_VAR_ANIMAL) String targetAnimal,
      @RequestParam(value = PARAM_FUR) @NotEmpty List<@NotBlank String> furs) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Imo a url change is not trivial and a breaking test is the proper scenario for this case. I also prefer readable urls instead of a concatenation of various strings which I will need to fit together to know what I'm actually invoking. My 2 cents at least.

Comment: Ok that makes sense and other collegues share this view. But I will still need to have the urls in one file for the tests. As there are muliple test per controller (unit, component and integration). I think it is not good to have to change the urls in all of the test classes. I am now thinking about creating an enum with all the urls of the controller under test. This enum would be only used in the tests.